# Scala SAM: how to access protected members of the SAM trait when implementing using a lambda?

Tags: scala

How can I access the protected methods of a SAM trait when **implementing said SAM using a lambda**?

E.g., this compiles just fine:

```
trait Foo {
  def foo(): String
  val bar = 5
}

val f: Foo = () => f.bar.toString
```

But these don't:

```
trait Foo {
  def foo(): String
  protected val bar = 5
}

val f: Foo = () => f.bar.toString // Symbol bar is inaccessible from this place
val f: Foo = () => bar.toString // Cannot resolve symbol bar
```

Is there any way to access bar when implementing a SAM **with a lambda**?

Comment: A lambda does not extend anything, you therefore cannot access super properties. Once you want to do this, do not use SAM.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
val f: Foo = new Foo {
  override def foo(): String = bar.toString
}
```

Comment: I should have been clearer: I want to still use a lambda.

Comment: You can't unless `val f: Foo = () => f.bar.toString` is a member inside object/class/trait extending `Foo`.